# Subtract consecutive rasters from a list in Python

Tags: python, raster, pyqgis

I have a list of 15 rasters as

b1.tiff
b2.tiff
b3.tiff
b4.tiff

I want to subtract the consecutive rasters, say b1.tiff from b2.tiff, b2.tiff from b3.tiff and so.

I see code with R but I want to do in Python. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Use zip and enumerate:

```
import os
in_folder = '/home/bera/GIS'
files = ['b1.tif', 'b2.tif', 'b3.tif', 'b4.tif']
files = [os.path.join(in_folder, f) for f in files]
out_folder = '/home/bera/GIS/out'

for e, (r1,r2) in enumerate(zip(files,files[1:]),1):
    outraster = os.path.join(out_folder,'Out_{0}_{1}.tif'.format(e,e+1))
    processing.run("gdal:rastercalculator", 
        {'INPUT_A':r1,'BAND_A':1,
        'INPUT_B':r2,'FORMULA':'A-B','NO_DATA':None, #Or do you mean 'B-A'?
        'RTYPE':5,'OPTIONS':'','EXTRA':'','OUTPUT':outraster})
```

Comment: Total 15 rasters, added the same to the post. For one pair it is working fine, but not sure how to perform the same in a loop for all the 15 rasters.